# Proper way to change URL address with loop

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot, url

So I am trying to get the information from a specific API and copy it's data in my database (for test purposes).
Here is my code so far:

```
private static final String GAME_URL = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games";
private static final String API_KEY = "250b2de5e7734f638760ae2bad9bd29f";
private int GAME_ID = 1;
private StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(GAME_URL + "/" + GAME_ID + "?key=" + API_KEY);

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private final GameService gameService;

public FetchGameApiService(GameService gameService) {
    this.gameService = gameService;
}


@PostConstruct
public void getGameById(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        GameDto gameDto = restTemplate.getForObject(URL.toString(), GameDto.class);
        if(!checkIfGameValidity(gameDto.getName())){
            gameService.saveGame(gameDto);
        }
        GAME_ID++;
    }
}
```

It seems interesting that for each loop the Game_ID is increasing, however the url always stays the same (instead of api/games/2 or api/games/3 it always stays api/games/1).
My question is the following: how can I fix this problem? does it have something to do with Strings? and also is this a proper way to loop though an api and store it in the  database?

Comment: move the StringBuilder inside the loop

Comment: Yeah it works now, when i moved string builder in for loop. However, is this a good practice? should i create new instance of string builder everytime i run though loop?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `StringBuilder` in a way like `new StringBuilder("foo" + bar + "bam")`. Notice that `"foo" + bar + "bam"` already creates a string which you are passing to StringBuilder. But to create such string compiler will need to generate code equivalent to something like `new StrinBuilder(new StringBuilder("foo").append(bar).append("bam").toString())` so two StringBuilder objects will be created which will be inefficient (the outer one is simply no longer needed). In short don't use concatenation operator `+` on StringBuilder, use `append` instead.

Comment: Anyway we use StringBuilder in a loop when we want to dynamically *add* new value to string which is built. In your case you want to *replace* some content of string so using StringBuilder is not required. Simple `String currentURL = GAME_URL + "/" + (GAME_ID++) + "?key=" + API_KEY;` in a loop should be enough.